# Adding span tag in to wordpress menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm new to wordpress and I'm trying to figure out things on my own.

But I stuck here,

This is my HTML menu,

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"><span class="menu-link">About us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html"><span class="menu-link">Blog</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html"><span class="menu-link">Gallery</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"><span class="menu-link">Contact us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to convert this in to wordpress and I did it in below way,

But I want to add `<span class="menu-link">` this tag as my HTML code.
Literally I want to convert that HTML in to WORDPRESS

THIS is my header.php

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
array(
'menu' => 'primary',
'container' => '',
'theme_location' => 'primary',
'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>'
)
);
?>
```

This is my function.php

```
function alleg_menus(){ // Create new menu locations
    $locations = array(
        'primary' => "Desktop Primary Top Menu",
        'footer' => "Footer Menu Items"
    );
    register_nav_menus($locations);
}
add_action('init', 'alleg_menus');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like below code?

```
wp_nav_menu(
array(
'menu' => 'primary',
'container' => '',
'theme_location' => 'primary',
'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>', 'link_before'=>'<span class="menu-link">', 'link_after'=>'</span>'
)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter.

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'ls_span_to_nav_menu', 10, 4 );
function ls_span_to_nav_menu( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {

    $item_output = '<a href="'. $item->url .'" title="'. $item->attr_title .'"><span class="menu-link">'.$item->post_title.'</span >'</a>';
    

    return $item_output;
}
```